# CodenameOne Problems on Ant-Build

Tags: ant, codenameone

I Would like to ask for some help for my codenameone build.
I can't figure out what causes this error.

The Error description everything i recieved :
`build.xml:78: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

My Context around line 78 Build.xml File:
The error happends by the classpath.

```
<target name="-pre-compile" depends="-cn1-compile-css">
    <echo>Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This
        allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
    </echo>
    <mkdir dir="build/tmp"/>
    <javac destdir="build/tmp"
           encoding="${source.encoding}"
           source="1.8"
           target="1.8"
           bootclasspath="lib/CLDC11.jar" excludes="${excludes}"
           classpath="${javac.classpath}:${build.classes.dir}">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
        <withKotlin>
            <compilerarg value="-no-stdlib"/>
            <compilerarg value="-no-reflect"/>
            <compilerarg value="-no-jdk"/>
        </withKotlin>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: You need to include the error itself from the IDE console. You used APIs that aren't supported by Codename One. If you scroll a bit up in the errors you would see compilation problems. Notice that ANT projects let you import invalid libraries and invoke them, this isn't as big a problem in the newer maven projects.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, thanks for your reply. Is there a way to find out wich api is not supported ?

Comment: Look up in the console where you saw this error. It should all be printed in the lines above that.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog this didn't help me :/ But i have changed the jdk of the Projekt to the CodeNameOne jars this helped to localize the errors.